# QOpenGLShaderProgram can't be created on Qt5.5

Tags: opengl-es, qt5

I'm working on a project on embedded ununtu 14.04 with opengl es 1.1/2.0 support, and the program in built with Qt5.5.
When the program is running, I met the same problem as the link below:
[question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996146/qglshaderprogram-will-not-compile-any-shader-since-upgrading-to-qt5)

So my questions are:
1. How can I set in program to solve this problem?
2. And if it's impossible for me to do something to solve this problem, can I compile the shader files with other tools and linked it to the program?

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page to figure out why the shader isn't compiling. Then you can try and fix that.

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation

Especially the section on Error Handling.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the problem, it seems like there are more differences in openGL and openGL es tha I need to learn.

Comment: I solved this problem by using QOpenglTexture class.